# Is this code idiomatic? Are there better or more concise ways to write this?

Tags: clojure

i'm trying to model a game of poker.

My game state representation is in a map, for this question i'm only interested in the players.

`{:players {:1 {:money 200} :2 {money 400}}}`

Every function takes in a game state and some other parameters and return a new game state, for example:

```
(defn update-player-money
  "Returns new game state where player has added amount to his money"
  [game-state player amount]
  (assoc-in game-state [:players player :money]
            (+ (-> game-state :players player :money)
               amount)))
```

Now i want a function that removes a certain amount of money from each player while passing down the new game state.
To make it clear, something that for two players would do:

```
(update-player-money (update-player-money game-state :1 (- 20)) :2 (-20))
```

This is what i came up with:

```
(defn phase-1-blind
  "Removes blind from all players."
  [game-state blind-amount]
  (letfn [(blind-helper [game-state player-list amount]
            (if (seq player-list)
              (blind-helper (update-player-money game-state
                                                 (first player-list)
                                                 (- amount))
                            (rest player-list)
                            amount)
              game-state))]
  (blind-helper game-state (keys (:players game-state)) blind-amount)))
```

This works but i was wondering if there was a more idiomatic or concise way to achieve the same effect.

Comment: have you checked `update-in` ?

Comment: `update-in` would certainly improve the `update-player-money` function. Would there be a better alternative than writing the recursion by hand in the second function?

Comment: Another food for thoughts: if you separate updating the money of a player and updating the money of a player inside the gamestate, you can reuse the previous function.

Comment: `:1` isn't idiomatic. Just use 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to implement `phase-1-blind` using `update-player-money`, [`reduce`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reduce) is useful here:

```clj
(defn update-player-money
  "Returns new game state where player has added amount to his money"
  [game player-id amt]
  (update-in game [:players player-id :money] (fnil + 0) amt))

(defn phase-1-blind
  "Removes blind from all players."
  [game blind]
  (reduce #(update-player-money % %2 blind)
          game
          (keys (:players game))))
```

In `update-player-money`, [`fnil`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/fnil) makes sure things don't break, even if a player doesn't have the `:money` key in it.